# What addresses can be a primary place of business for an LLC in Florida?

Tags: business, florida, limited-liability-company

According to the [Florida "SunBiz" website](https://dos.myflorida.com/sunbiz/start-business/efile/fl-llc/instructions/), the Article of Organization must list a "Principal Place of Business Address" in addition to a mailing address and the registered agent address. Those instructions make it clear that:

a) a PO Box is acceptable for the Mailing Address

and

b) the registered agent must have a physical address

but says almost nothing about the nature or requirements of "principal place of business."

My question is, for a LLC that will have no physical location where it conducts business, what addresses can be listed? I don't want to use my personal home address for obvious reasons of privacy.

- Can I use my registered agent address (assuming the registered agent service I use will agree to it)? If so, is that typical?
- Can I use a basic PO Box (as opposed to a more sophisticated and expensive "virtual office" service)?

Comment: You probably need a street address as a principal office, but I am too lazy to do the research today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional research, including talking with a couple of registered agent services, the answer is that the Principal Place of Business address *is* required to be a physical street address. However, some registered agent services allow you to use their office address as your LLC's principal address (if you hire them as your registered agent, of course).